# How to render Symbol(react.element) to HTML

Tags: reactjs, react-tabs

I'm new to React and I'm working with the react-table library. But I need to export the result as HTML. I've created a basic HTML structure and wanted to add the table, however it returns [object Object] and if I console.log the return value it logs as:

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}
```

Thanks in advance